# Multiprocessing and shared library - locks

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, shared-libraries, gdal

My case looks like I have `N` workers run async. They are started from `GUI` app. All of them are doing the same thing but for different data. They use `GDAL` library for raster operations. When I observe output data (some `png` files that are being created). It looks like they are creating files one by one (not in the same time). What is strange I set processor affinity (each process has his own core) and nothing happend with output data. I started reading something in the web and I have found that if I have a shared library (`GDAL` in my case), than if it's compiled as `STA`, it can be locked by these processes separately... Can anyone describe how it works? Is my lib really locked when one of the working processes wants to execute some method from it?

Comment: Just so it's perfectly clear...are you saying that surfing the web via IE (or any other browser) will effect the execution of your .NET application? Regardless, you may have better luck asking the GDAL folks directly.

Comment: It's not a question about how GDAL works, but if someone knew, it would be good. I want to know as if the lib is compiled as STA and used by several processes (and e.g. it has some locks inside on static methods doing some calculations), then can it make the processes lock each other in the critical sections of the lib?